# Date conversion failed from string

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a date saved in the format DD/MM/YYYY from a flat file. "20/04/2013"

When I try to insert it into my SQL Server database it changes the value to MM/DD/YYYY.

So of course there in no month 20 and my code fail. How can I work around this?

I have tried stuff like this and I had no luck.

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar, '20/04/2013', 101))
```

Comment: 101 is code for US Format, you are exactly telling your convert to use MM/DD/YYYY - You should use 103 which is DD/MM/YYYY. More about cast and convert codes at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just do this directly,

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '20/04/2013', 103)
```

Answer (score 1):

On SQL Server you need to use the `SET DATEFORMAT` option. (See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx).

In your case, you would need to issue the following command before executing the above SELECT-statement:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy
```

Alternatively, it is possible to globally change the DATEFORMAT setting for the server.

Answer (score 0):

Definition and Usage
The CONVERT() function is a general function that converts an expression of one data type to another.

The CONVERT() function can be used to display date/time data in different formats.

select  convert(datetime, '20/04/2013', 103)
[enter link description here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)